# NodeJS - ChildProcess execFile - Uncaught Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to run a unix executable as an external application via node.js: ([Reference](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback))

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const executable = execFile('identifiers', ['--help'], [execPath], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('stderr', stderr);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('stdout', stdout);
});
```

The program **`identifiers`** should be executed with argument `--help`, instead fails with:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: spawn identifiers ENOENT
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264)
>     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80)
> ```

`console.log(execPath)` prints the correct **`identifiers`** exec path, within my node project.

---

This actually returns the directory of the root node project and exits with code 0:

```
var sys   = require('sys'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-l']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('exit code ' + code);
});
```

---

- **Why does `execFile` throw the error?**
- **How to appropriately run executables with args in NodeJS?**

Comment: why is your execPath inside an array on the options parameter? the docs say it is expecting an object

Comment: Thanks for the hint @innis I should've been more thorough when reading the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @innis for pointing out that the parameter should be an `<Object>`:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const executable = execFile('./identifiers', ['--id', '1'], {'cwd': execPath}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('stderr', stderr);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('stdout', stdout);
});
```

Comment: Glad i could help.